# iPhone app running on iPad (Compatibility mode)

Tags: ios

I just built an iPhone app. I was told that this app should automatically run on the iPad in compatibility mode. However, this is not happening when I run my app on the iPad simulator. The screen is weirdly cropped (please see below).

**App on iPhone simulator**

[image: App on iPhone simulator]

**App on iPad simulator**

[image]

Is there anything special that I need to do in order be able to run my app on the iPad (compatibility mode)? I already have iPhone selected under project > General > Deployment Info > Devices.

I am obligated to do this because of the following App Store requirement:

**iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution**

Comment: iPhone apps run at the iPhone4/s resolution when on the iPad which is why it's cropped but if you use autoLayout or even just have conditional statements in your UI code then you will be able to get it to display correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually compatibility mode.  That is how all iPhone only apps will look on the iPad. If you built the application using auto layout, you can enable your application to be universal and see how the app fills the screen of the iPad as full support iPad app.

Comment: I am not worried that the application does not fill the entire screen. Its just that the screen is cropped. Sometimes I have buttons at the bottom of the app that the user does not have access to in compatibility mode because the screen is cropped.

Comment: The screen is not "cropped"  If you have UI elements that are not on screen, it is because auto layout is not properly implemented.  You would probably have a similar issue running the app on an iPhone 4S simulator.